# Why won't make DialogWait Box close automatically?

Tags: java

so I want this dialog box to close when `wait1.close()` is called, but it doesn't disappear. I have to manually hit the 'X' button to close it and have the program go on to the next step. Any suggestions? I was able to implement a dialog box the same way that worked earlier in my code, but that implementation doesn't work here for some reason. Thanks!

This is where it's being used

```
    final ArrayList<ArrayList<Booking>> allAvailablePaths1 =allAvailablePaths;

        DialogWait wait1=new DialogWait();
        SwingWorker<Void,Void> mySwingWorker1=new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception{
                sort(x,allAvailablePaths1, paths);
                wait1.close();
                System.out.println("This line is printed");
                return null;

            }

        };
        mySwingWorker1.execute();
        wait1.makeWait("Thank You For Your Patience");
        return paths;
    }
```

And here is my DialogWait class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogWait {

    private JDialog dialog;

    public void makeWait(String msg) {

        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        dialog = new JDialog(frame, msg, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(100,20));
        panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Please wait......."), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void close() {
       dialog.dispose();
   }
}
```